# What does "lawforce flags" mean?

Tags: serenity

In *Serenity* (2005), the crew contacts reclusive hacker Mr. Universe, who discovers the message
designed to trigger River's mental conditioning:

> Malcolm: Well, what about this? Did this make the puppet theater?
>
> Mr Universe: No, sir. And no **lawforce flags**, either. I had to go into the
> security feed direct.

What does "lawforce flags" mean?

Comment: This refers to the fact that the incident with River did not make it on the news or raise any flags with law enforcement. Mr. Universe had to go directly to the feed of the fight to understand what happened.

Comment: @SDH - basically that's the answer.

Comment: @Valorum I know someone will come along and pretty it up. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'*Lawforce*' is Mr Universe's slang for "Alliance Law Enforcement". These are federal police (who can arrest you anywhere), as opposed to local police or private security.

> After all, that was what the Alliance did, wasn’t it? It controlled. It ran every aspect of life in the civilized parts of the ’verse, from what you ate to what you bought, from the level of society in which you moved to the rules that governed your daily routine. The Alliance, with its troops and **its law-enforcement operatives** and its tame corporations and its bought-and-paid-for politicians, held everything tight in its tentacles. Even out on the Rim you couldn’t escape it.
>
> <sub><sup>[Firefly: The Magnificent Nine](https://firefly.fandom.com/wiki/Firefly_-_The_Magnificent_Nine)</sup></sub>

A '*flag*' would be a bulletin notification on the Cortex about wanted fugitives and/or their ship.

> “Well, seems you got no choice but to keep my goods in your hold and
> get the ruddy ’ell out of here.” He tapped the tablet with his finger.
> “This is a bulletin, just got sent out all across the Cortex. Feds are
> hot on your tail. Seems you people have something they want. What is
> that, I wonder? What you got on board they’re so flaming interested
> in?”
>
> <sub><sup>[Firefly: Big Damn Hero](https://firefly.fandom.com/wiki/Firefly_-_Big_Damn_Hero)</sup></sub>